# JSON and PHP arrays

Tags: php, arrays, object, json

```php
json_encode(array(
    array(0 => "431.940054495913"),
    array(1 => "431.940054495913"),
));
```

Is rendered like this:

```javascript
[
    ["431.940054495913"],
    {"1":"431.940054495913"}
]
```

Why are the two arrays rendered differently ?

Comment: Difficult to understand what is being asked. Everything looks normal to me.

Comment: He wants to know why the elements with key '0' and key '1' are different when converted to JSON

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Any PHP array that can be rendered as a JSON array will be rendered as a JSON array: Any PHP array having only sequential numeric keys starting from 0 will be rendered as a JSON array.

This is the case for the first array: `array(0 => "431.940054495913")`.

#### How to fix this

- The [`JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`](http://docs.php.net/json_encode#refsect1-function.json-encode-parameters) flag will render all PHP arrays as JSON objects

  ```
  json_encode(array(0 => "431.940054495913"), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
  // {"0": "431.940054495913"}

  json_encode(array(0 => "431.940054495913"));
  // ["431.940054495913"]
  ```
- Alternatively, you could convert your PHP array to a PHP object:

  ```
  json_encode( (object) array(0 => "431.940054495913"));
  // {"0": "431.940054495913"}
  ```

  (if you don't want to render every array as object or if you don't have JSON_FORCE_OBJECT)

Comment: Thanks. Tried both and they both fix the issue. Good to know :)